# How to set the orientation of an Image View programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, uiimageview

I'm looking for, what I hope is, a quick solution to a problem I'm having regarding image view orientation in xcode 6. I would like to be able to change the angle of an image view through the viewcontroller class file, preferably by changing a property value. Ideally I'm hoping something similar to

```
@IBOutlet weak var Picture: UIImageView!

func changeangle(angleValue: int) {
Picture.angle = angleValue
}
```

but am really open to any solution. I've checked apple's developer library, but couldn't find anything (maybe I missed something though). Also, if it could be in swift, that would be awesome, but obj-c works too. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try like:

```
Picture.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angleValue / 180.0 * M_PI)
```

For a brief understanding of `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation` have a look at [this doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGAffineTransformMakeRotation) as well.

Comment: Thanks a million, you're awesome :) Worked perfectly!

Comment: Note minor changes in Swift 2 : Need to "CGFloatify" the func argument. `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(angleValue / 180.0 * M_PI))`